Explicit issue- pressure-driven rotating disk
I am trying to model a 3D deformable disk to rotate along its center by a pressure that applies in one end of the disk (as shown below), this disk is sliding and rotating on a discrete rigid plate that is place at the bottom of the disk, so the disk can rotate on it, I have used Explicit solver for the analysis and used Tetra elements for meshing. However, after running the analysis for a short period of time, it seems that the disk is not rotating!

I have applied surface to surface (explicit) Interaction between the rigid bottom plate and deformable disk and also defined General Contact (explicit) for this purpose, with a small Friction coef (0.1) as penalty interaction.
enter image description here
I have applied Encastre bc for the bottom rigid body, so it won't move and applied (U2=UR1=UR3=0) for the deformable disk. After running the analysis, it seems that the disk is not rotating!
I'd appreciate your opinions.


Your diagrams appear to have lugs that stick out and will prevent rotation by more than a few degrees. This question is unanswerable as posed and nothing like a minimal reproducible example. I have no idea what the random mush of magenta arrows is supposed to represent. Also do you mean pressure, torque or force? What is the Young's modulus of the deformable disk?
